# Placing the caret between two elements in a content editable container in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, contenteditable

Try the example below in Chrome and Firefox. It's two adjacent uneditable elements in a content editable container. In Firefox, there's no way to put the caret between them, while in Chrome there is, and you can type normally there too. Is there a way to get this behavior to work in FF?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  outline: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding:10px;
}

span {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable>
  <span contenteditable="false"></span>
  <span contenteditable="false"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: where and what is  the caret? don't see it using chrome

Comment: It's the text cursor. Click on the container or the inner elements, and it'll show up in since the container is content editable. Use the keyboard to get it between the elements and type. This'll work fine in Chrome, but in Firefox, you cant even get it to show up.